# How to show only increases in a graph in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

This is my current graph with the query of `sum by (job) (requests{job="CDN",exported_instance="push_19"})`. How can I remove the break show only increases? Like a linear graph.

[image]

Let's say the results is like:

10, 12, ***9*** ,10
I want it to become
10, 12, 13

As far as I know the metric is gauge:

```
curl -G http://**********:9090/api/v1/targets/metadata \
>     --data-urlencode 'metric=requests' \
>     --data-urlencode 'match_target={job="CDN"}' \
>     --data-urlencode 'limit=2'
{"status":"success","data":[{"target":{"instance":"localhost:9091","job":"CDN"},"type":"gauge","help":"requests count","unit":""}]}
```

What I've done so far:

- `sum by (job) (increase(requests{job="CDN",exported_instance="push_19"} [1h]))` the values are incorrect. The real sum is about 240M but the result of this query is about 10k

[image]

- `sum by (job) (sum_over_time (requests{job="CDN",exported_instance="push_19"}[1h]))` the break still exists also the values are incorrect
  [image]
- `sum(running_sum(increase(requests))) by (job)` throws the following error
  `Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': parse error at char 16: unknown function with name "running_sum"`

Comment: Is "requests" a "gauge"? Is it the second graph showed?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira the second graph (blue graphs) has nothing to do with prometheus, it's just an example from Tradingview website.

Comment: You need to know if your metric is a gauge or a counter. If you show the real metric graph it would help to understand the issue.

Comment: Try `sum(running_sum(increase(requests))) by (job)` in [MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html).

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira It must be `gauge`. I've updated the answer and the output of curl metadata is gauge

Comment: @valyala thanks for your attention, I get the `unknown function with name "running_sum"` error

Comment: Unfrotunately the `running_sum` function isn't supported by PromQL. This is [MetricsQL function](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) from [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics).